# models.ForeignKey() in django

Tags: python, django, web, backend

Here is my code

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So I'm kinda confused with what `models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)` do, what does "default" mean here?

And I'm also confused what `models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` do, what is "on_delete=models.CASCADE" do and mean?

And is this code ( `from django.contrib.auth.models` ) a database for users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)` do, what does "default" mean here?

You can pass a callable to the `default=…` parameter. When the model object is the created, and there is no value for `date_posted`, it will call the `timezone.now` function and use the result as value for the `date_posted`.

> And I'm also confused what `models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` do, what is `on_delete=models.CASCADE` do and mean?

A `ForeignKey` refers to an object. The question is what to do if the object it is referring to is removed. With [**`on_delete=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) you can specify a strategy. `CASCADE` means that it will remove the `Post`(s) from a `User`, if that `User` is removed itself.

> And is this code ( from django.contrib.auth.models ) a database for users?

These are models defined in the `auth` app. Django has such app to make it easy to start with a simple user model, but you can decide to impelement your own. It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed information, this helps